# Force footer to stay at bottom of page

Tags: html, css, footer

Currently, i've got a footer at the bottom of the viewpoint but i'd like it to be at the bottom of the webpage. I'd like this because it overlaps most of the content on each page. How can I change the below HTML and CSS to fix this?

```css
body {
    background-color: #40E39C;
    }
#nav-menu a {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px 45px 30px 45px;
    }
#nav-menu ul{
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
#nav-menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 40px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 30px 45px 30px 45px;
    }  
.footer {
    background-color: #EAEDD0;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    }
.footer li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.footer ul {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="nav-menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="./a.php">A</a></li>
            <li><a href="./b.php">B</a></li>
            <li><a href="./c.php">C</a></li>
            <li><a href="./d.php">D</a></li>
            <li><a href="./e.php">E</a></li>
            <li><a href="./f.php">F</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="./a.php">A | </a></li>
            <li><a href="./b.php">B | </a></li>
            <li><a href="./c.php">C | </a></li>
            <li><a href="./d.php">D | </a></li>
            <li><a href="./e.php">E | </a></li>
            <li><a href="./f.php">F</a></li>
        </ul>
</footer>
</body>
```

**UPDATE**

I've removed the css

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
```

and added

```
display: relative;
```

to the body tag, but the footer still has some space between the bottom of the page and it.

```css
body {
  background-color: #40E39C;
  position: relative;
}

#nav-menu a {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px 45px 30px 45px;
}

#nav-menu ul {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

#nav-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 40px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 30px 45px 30px 45px;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #EAEDD0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}

.footer li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.footer ul {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="nav-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="./a.php">A</a></li>
      <li><a href="./b.php">B</a></li>
      <li><a href="./c.php">C</a></li>
      <li><a href="./d.php">D</a></li>
      <li><a href="./e.php">E</a></li>
      <li><a href="./f.php">F</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <p>a<p/>
  <p>a<p/>
  <p>a<p/>
  <p>a<p/>
  <p>a<p/>
  <p>a<p/>
  v
  <p>a<p/><p>a<p/>
  <p>a<p/>
  <p>a<p/>
  v
  v
  v<p>a<p/><p>a<p/><p>a<p/>
  <footer class="footer">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="./a.php">A | </a></li>
      <li><a href="./b.php">B | </a></li>
      <li><a href="./c.php">C | </a></li>
      <li><a href="./d.php">D | </a></li>
      <li><a href="./e.php">E | </a></li>
      <li><a href="./f.php">F</a></li>
    </ul>
  </footer>
</body>
```

**Maybe this might help**
This is my gallery page. I hope you can find the problem a bit easier with this.

```css
#nav-menu a {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px 45px 30px 45px;
    }

#nav-menu ul{
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

#nav-menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 40px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 30px 45px 30px 45px;
    }
    
.footer {
    background-color: #EAEDD0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    }

.footer li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.footer ul {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <div id="nav-menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="./a.php">A</a></li>
        <li><a href="./b.php">B</a></li>
        <li><a href="./c.php">C</a></li>
        <li><a href="./d.php">D</a></li>
        <li><a href="./e.php">E</a></li>
        <li><a href="./f.php">F</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;">
        <img src="images/hotelRoom1.jpg" width="360" height="210" style="float:left; padding: 0px 0px 20px 20px;"/>
        <img src="images/hotelRoom2.jpg" width="360" height="210" style="float:right; padding: 0px 20px 20px 0px"/>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;">
        <img src="images/hotelRoom3.jpg" width="360" height="210" style="float:left; padding: 0px 0px 20px 20px;"/>
        <img src="images/hotelRoom4.jpg" width="360" height="210" style="float:right; padding: 0px 20px 20px 0px"/>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;">
        <img src="images/hotelRoom5.jpg" width="360" height="210" style="float:left; padding: 0px 0px 20px 20px;"/>
        <img src="images/hotelRoom6.jpg" width="360" height="210" style="float:right; padding: 0px 20px 20px 0px"/>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="./a.php">A | </a></li>
        <li><a href="./b.php">B | </a></li>
        <li><a href="./c.php">C | </a></li>
        <li><a href="./d.php">D | </a></li>
        <li><a href="./e.php">E | </a></li>
        <li><a href="./f.php">F</a></li>
    </ul>
    </footer>

</body>
```

Code snip of an attempt to fix.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XV62.png]

Comment: Have you tried     body{margin:0; padding:0;} ?

Comment: I've just tried that and it doesn't work!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of forms seem to keep footer attached to content; not sticky at bottom of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49758538/use-of-forms-seem-to-keep-footer-attached-to-content-not-sticky-at-bottom-of-pa)

Comment: you can find the answer to this question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49758538/use-of-forms-seem-to-keep-footer-attached-to-content-not-sticky-at-bottom-of-pa

Comment: and to explain everything to you , you can't duplicate question and to be clear check this : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled

welcome to stackoverflow

Answer (score 4):

Add this CSS:

```
body {
  position: relative;
}
```

Also add two CSS prop to your `.footer` class. So your `.footer` CSS will be like:

```
.footer {
  background-color: #EAEDD0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

And this is working as I have checked it in code snip.

Comment: @NickWright Please add above css and check it again.

Comment: I've added that code to my css but I'm not seeing the footer at the bottom of the webpage. It's at the bottom of the viewport yes but not at the bottom of the page...

Comment: hey now i got your issue. You dont want a fixed footer to bottom.
Now no need to add any other CSS which i have added in this answer. Just add overflow : hidden to .footer class. Your issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following code from .footer css

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to resolve my problem fully. I need the footer at the bottom of the page, but for some reason now there is some space between the bottom and the footer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position:fixed` from the `.footer` and also remove unnecessary left, bottom etc. Final styles for footer is:

```
.footer {
    background-color: #EAEDD0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

### Update for clearfix and Unwanted Margin

Problem is not on our solution. In your code snipped there are 2 other cause preventing you to get your expected result. You didn't use clearfix on right place and there is some small margin on body causing the space. The solution for clearfix is here:

```
div:after{
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

You should give those style to every parent which having children with float left or right.

And as I am finding browser given margin on `body` the fix is to give:

```
body{margin: 0}
```

Comment: Please could you check my updated question to help me out?

Comment: I believe that `display: relative` on your update is a typo. You actually did `position: relative`. And the space between your footer and end of the page is because of the margin of `ul` auto generated by your browser. On this `ul` on `footer` use `margin:0` to remove the space

Comment: Ah yes that was a typo but it still didn't fix it!

Comment: It's because of wrong `clearfix` and browser given margin on `body` you are not having your expected result. I have updated the answer.